# Performance improvements from ASP.NET Core 2.1 for full .NET framework?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an existing project basing on ASP.NET Core 2.0 running on full .NET framework. Microsoft doc of my case is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.0). The application is using Kestrel with libuv to serve incoming connections.

**Theoretically, how does ASP.NET Core 2.1 improve/demote the performance of my case?**

My project is running on full .NET Framework 4.7.2. It seems to me it will not benefited by the [Performance Improvements in .NET Core 2.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/04/18/performance-improvements-in-net-core-2-1/). Right?

Also [ASP.NET Core 2.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/05/30/asp-net-core-2-1-0-now-available/) release note mentioned.

> Managed sockets replace libuv as Kestrel's default transport.

Does that make a lot of difference to the app running on full .NET framework?

Comment: There are a lot of differences that aren't related to Kestrel. Check [this article about 2.0 perf improvements](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/06/07/performance-improvements-in-net-core/). 2x faster Queue operations. 600x faster SortedSet.  30%-60% faster concurrent collection operators etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Since you are running on the .NET Framework, you are not affected by the performance improvements that were made with .NET Core 2.1. While the changes there are general changes that will eventually reach the .NET Framework as well (at least partially), we simply aren’t there yet.

If you want the best performance, then you should use .NET Core, which will always be the runtime where the most improvements will be made and where improvements will happen first.

However, that does not mean that the .NET Framework is slow or anything. Countless applications have been built on the .NET Framework in the past and that includes lots of really performance-critical things as well. Even Stack Overflow currently runs on the .NET Framework. So just because .NET Core can be *faster*, that does not make the .NET Framework bad. It’s perfectly fine to run on the full framework.

That being said, ASP.NET Core 2.1 of course also includes changes that may affect the performance. While most of the announced speed improvements come from the .NET Core 2.1 changes, it wouldn’t be surprising if there are other changes that will also show noticeable improvements. The Sockets transport layer is one of those.

Regardless of performance improvements, you should upgrade from 2.0 to 2.1 anyway. .NET Core 2.0 and ASP.NET Core 2.0 will [reach EOL on October 1st 2018](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/06/20/net-core-2-0-will-reach-end-of-life-on-september-1-2018/). So by that time, you should have upgraded if you want support from Microsoft.

Comment: There are a lot of perf improvements in LINQ, collections etc that will affect the application simply by switching to .NET Core 2.x, like those described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/06/07/performance-improvements-in-net-core/).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, but this question is about being on the .NET Framework. OP is asking whether there are performance improvements for .NET Framework when switching to 2.1, knowing that there were a lot advancements with .NET Core.

Comment: Which version of .NET framework will include those improvements?  seems they will not appear in .Net Framework 4.8

Comment: @Mr.WangfromNextDoor So far, that’s not yet known. I would assume that it will still take quite a while before we see those changes reach the framework. So if you really *need* those improvements, better switch to Core.